# E492: UltiSnips not an editor command

Tags: vim, code-snippets, ultisnips

When I'm trying to use UltiSnips, it returns this error:

```
E492: Not an editor command: snippet test "Test Snippet"
E492: Not an editor command: Test
E492: Not an editor command: endsnippet
```

My .vimrc look like that: https://pastebin.com/0AwFks2J

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll be more likely to get an answer to your question if you write a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You should not generally use links to external sites to include all parts of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things.

1. You put `Plugin “SirVer/UltiSnips”` and `Plugin “honza/vim-snippets”` outside of your `call vundle#begin()...call vundle#end()` block, you’ll need to move those in order for those plugins to be loaded.
2. Snippets are not supposed to be defined in your vimrc. They are supposed to be defined in `*.snippets` files. By default, UltiSnips looks for an `UltiSnips` directory inside directories in your `'runtimepath'`. You could create a `~/.vim/UltiSnips` directory if it doesn’t exist and put your `*.snippets` flies there.

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped me!